# Restrict operations to the REMOTE domain

Tags: rubygems, command, installation, switch-statement

I had to install gem, and it was advised to use -r switch. If you use help or google, it gives you what in the subject. But what it truly means? What kind of operations does it restrict to the remote domain? What is the remote domain? The one from which the gem is downloaded?

Example:

```
gem install -r log4r
```

Answer (score 0):

Gems can be installed either from a local file (`.gem` extension) or downloaded from the server (`remote domain`).

By default, it will first search inside the current directory, then it will download from the server.

You have 2 command line options to control this:

`-l` forces the install from a local file

`-r` forces a download